# Can't access class from app_code folder in asp.net website project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm experiencing this trouble that I can't figure out a solution.

I have a asp.net website project. A class library in `app_code` folder named `Libs.cs` (class name is Libs too).

The problem is :

- if I want to reference the class in `*.aspx.cs` files, I have to set its Build Action property to : compile. This way I can reference the class without using the `using` Synxtax ( for example my namespace is IK, I don't have to include : `using IK;` )  , but I can't reference the class in the `.aspx file`
- if I want to reference the class in `*.aspx` files, I have to set its Build Action property to : `content`. This way I can reference the class using the `import` Syntax ( for example my namespace is IK, I have to include : `<%@ Import Namespace="IK" %>` ), but I can't reference the class in the `.aspx.cs` file

So now if I want to reference the class, I have to choose , `aspx` or `aspx.cs`. I tried to google and everything, but without success.

Comment: Got it! 

I created this project using : new-> new website project-> empty asp.net website project

but i don't know somehow it became Web Application Project

so using the app_code folder for containing class files is wrong

the solution is creating another folder for the classes

thanks for reading !

Comment: If you found the solution to your question, please post it as an answer so that other people can learn from it as well.

Comment: sorry i don't have enough reputation !

Comment: The ability to create a post starts at `1` reputation, take a look at the [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=creation).

Comment: Now You can answer here. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

I created this project using : new-> new website project-> empty asp.net website project

but i don't know somehow it became Web Application Project

so using the app_code folder for containing class files is wrong

the solution is creating another folder for the classes

thanks for readin

Comment: Had the exact same problem after reverting to .NET 4.0 from 4.5.2 (target server wasn't getting upgraded yet, so had to compile for a lower version) and I've found that creating another folder and moving the code there works. Now, the ultimate question is "WHY?"!  The files being in the `App_Code` folder or in a standard folder should not matter - at least to me.  Anyone know why it does?!